# Searching and Regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

As I am new in PHP.Here is my js code

```
      var sites = [
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal/", duration:9},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
  //Intro detallee
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t1.html", duration:35},
 //CTA
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t2.html", duration:35},
     //Football
  {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/twitter-ligue/", duration:100},  
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9},     
  //TrailersClub.com
  {url:"http://trailersclub.com/?lang=fr", duration:480},    
 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
 //Meteo
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/meteo", duration:12},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-cine/", duration:9},
 //Cine
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/cine/index-t1.html", duration:150},
  //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
 //Meteo
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/meteo", duration:12},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-cine/", duration:9},
   //Cine

 ];
```

I want to perform some search task like url and duration so as to display in seperate coloumn but when I perform Regx for http then nothing print on html.

Here is my rough PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://carouselinfo.com/contents.js');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
 $contents = json_encode($contents,true);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $contents;

 $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
 if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl,$contents,$url))
{
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $url;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `json_encode` call. It is not needed here and adds additional escaping around special chars, including turning `/` into a `\/`, which prevents your regex from matching.

Comment: @DCoder +1 I would even say json_encode is an error :)

Comment: @DCoder when I didn't use json_encode then echo $url print ARRAY

Comment: That's right, `preg_match_all` generates an *array* of matches, and `echo` can't handle those. Try `print_r` or `var_dump` instead.

Comment: Json_encode winll not work as its the parameter passed is not array or object rather string. json_decode is the function here should be used. But the string is JavaScript not JSON. So it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the json_encode call. Then apply following regex,

```
 /url\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"/
```

The code should look like.

```
$reg_exUrl = '/url\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"\s*,\s*duration\s*:\s*(\d+)/';
if (preg_match_all($reg_exUrl,$contents,$matches))
{
    print_r($matches[1]); // not using echo here
    print_r($matches[2]); 
}
```

Example [Php snippet](http://ideone.com/jDX0F)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im-show ARRAY in place of echo $url that why I use json_encode

Comment: so after that I want to do some task like print in each sepearte line with duration: then how should I print it

Comment: That's a very basic PHP. you should use loop.

Comment: mean first of all I find duration and then print each html with duration right?

Comment: Updated my answer. Now it captures duration too. But you have build the unified array as regex does not capture that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the json_encode is adding extra characters (the '\' escape character) or transforming other characters (to their ascii-encoded equivalent), which means your regexp fails to match.  You should run the regexp over the original value of $contents.  By the way, don't echo the whole $url value since this is an array.

Comment: So what should I use to print each url

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors, but How about saving your javascript var as a php var and doing a foreach loop?

Like this...

```
$sites = array('http://www.php.net/','http://stackoverflow.com/','http://www.godaddy.com/');
$duration = array('5','100','5000');

foreach($sites as $site){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

$reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
preg_match_all($reg_exUrl,$contents,$urls);
if(isset($urls)){

    var_dump($urls);

}
}
```

Comment: I edited the code a smidge, put in real websites, and put a var dump so you can see everything, run this script as is on a seperate file so you can see the output... It's looong

Comment: Is it what you are looking for? you will have to fix your regex i think, I didn't touch that.... not my forte.

Comment: No,I am looking for my code to work means I have js file first I use curl function yo extract and then I want to echo the url of that js file which is [url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t2.html", duration:35]i mean i want to extract url and duration